# Adding event to calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have this code for adding an event to the calendar:

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2013, 3, 23, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2013, 3, 24, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "My Test");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "My Calendar Test");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Israel/tel-aviv");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

It works correctly on my Galaxy S3, but on my Galaxy S2 it doesn't work - nothing happens - this is despite both having the same Android version - 4.1.2

Comment: Is it possible that you cannot add events that have happened in the past perhaps ? your times are for 23/3/2013 to 24/3/2013. Try to add a future event.

Comment: i try with today date and same problem

Comment: I found that it work good only when the calendar Directed to Outlook